# ошибка 400 при запросе к серверу microsoft face

Tags: python, api, requests

пытаюсь вернуть список людей в person group в micrpsoft azure face api, но получаю ошибку "{"error":{"code":"NotSupported","message":"The current operation is not supported."}}
400"
Прошу помочь. Вот ссылка на страничку https://westcentralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395241
вот функция:

```
def person_list(group):
url = 'https://westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/persongroups/{}/persons'.format(group)
headers = {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': key}
params = {'personGroupId': group}
response = requests.get(url, params=params,
                        headers=headers)
print(response.text)
print(response.status_code)
```

Comment: Что в group и key передаёте? Чтоб можно было протестировать.

Comment: group возьмите за 'alpha2', а ключ за 'cff7278eb1774e44bb49e4620a0b4886'

Comment: Access denied due to invalid subscription key. Make sure you are subscribed to an API you are trying to call and provide the right key.

Comment: АА, сори, мой ключ, который я использую на другом регионе, замените westeurope на westcentralus

Comment: Получил 200. И пустой список.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из запроса нужно убрать params. Группа передаётся строкой в теле url. Этого достаточно.

```
def person_list(group):
    url = 'https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/' + \
    'face/v1.0/persongroups/%s/persons' % group
    headers = {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': key}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    print(response.text)
    print(response.status_code)
```

Comment: спасибо,работает)